# Capistrano 3 deploy:migrate not executing due to missing primary

Tags: ruby-on-rails, migration, rake, capistrano, capistrano3

I have capistrano setup to deploy a rails application to a remote server. Everything is working fine in deploying the code, but even though I had the `capistrano-rails` gem installed, it was not migrating the database. The migrations work when I migrate them manually on the server, but it would be much nicer to have them run automatically

To try to figure out what was going wrong I went into the `capistrano-rails` source, and copied the `deploy:migrate` method directly into my deploy.rb file. I added a bunch of print lines and found that while it was entering the method, it wasn't returning anything because the line: `on primary fetch(:migration_role)` was returning an empty array.

The [capistrano documentation](http://capistranorb.com/documentation/getting-started/preparing-your-application/) refers to how the primary is defined says that the first listed role is the default primary if none is specified.

Here is the `capistrano-rails` source code that I inserted into my deploy.rb file, my only modification is the two `puts` lines.

```
namespace :deploy do
  desc 'Runs rake db:migrate if migrations are set'
  task :migrate => [:set_rails_env] do
    puts "on primary fetch(:migration_role) ==> #{on primary fetch(:migration_role)}"
    on primary fetch(:migration_role) do
      puts "+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++"
      conditionally_migrate = fetch(:conditionally_migrate)
      info '[deploy:migrate] Checking changes in /db/migrate' if conditionally_migrate
      if conditionally_migrate && test("diff -q #{release_path}/db/migrate #{current_path}/db/migrate")
        info '[deploy:migrate] Skip `deploy:migrate` (nothing changed in db/migrate)'
      else
        info '[deploy:migrate] Run `rake db:migrate`' if conditionally_migrate
        within release_path do
          with rails_env: fetch(:rails_env) do
            execute :rake, "db:migrate"
          end
        end
      end
    end
  end

  after :updated, :migrate
end
```

Here are a few other setting from my `staging.rb` role file that may be relevant. I changed my specific server names.

```
role :app, %w{deploy@example.com}
role :web, %w{deploy@example.com}


# Default deploy_to directory is /var/www/my_app
set :deploy_to, '/path/to/my/staging_dir'


# Define server(s)
server 'example.com', user: 'deploy', roles: %w{web app}

# Setup Options
set :migration_role, 'migrator'
set :conditionally_migrate, true
set :assets_roles, [:web, :app]
```

Let me know if you have any idea as to what might be going wrong here. Thanks!

Comment: **Update**

I tried adding in the `:db` role to my staging.rb role file, and even tried explicitly setting the `:migration_role` on that server like in the line below, but the array within the source code is still empty and the same issue persists.

`role :db,  %w{deployer@buri.peckapp.com}, :primary => true, :migration_role => %w(db)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured out that the issue was with duplicate server definitions. Because I had the role definitions:

```
role :app, %w{deploy@example.com}
role :web, %w{deploy@example.com}
```

and the server definition:

```
server 'example.com', user: 'deploy', roles: %w{web app db}
```

a conflict between those two was coming up that prevented anything from being properly recognized by the migration code.

Answer (score 9):

Add 'db' to your server's roles:

```
server 'example.com', user: 'deploy', roles: %w{web app db}
```

Also, in your `Capfile`:

```
require 'capistrano/rails/migrations'
```

I believe you will also want these require statements in your `Capfile` as well:

```
require 'capistrano/bundler'
require 'capistrano/rails/assets'
```

Comment: I did already have those requirements in my Capfile, and unfortunately adding 'db' to the server roles didn't seem to make a difference. The call to `on primary fetch(:migration_role)` is still returning an empty array in the source and preventing the the actual rake migration task from executing. Could there be a setting that I'm missing for :migration_role? I found the [pull request](https://github.com/capistrano/rails/pull/12/files) adding it but it doesn't shed much light. What does `on primary` do? Could the issue be stemming from there? I updated the question with a few things.